# Filling up 2’ deep patch to plant lavender

Tags: lavender

i dug up a small patch (12’ x 6’) which was full of rubble and a bit of sand. It is now 2’ deep from the surface. I’m planning to fill it up with soil and plant lavender. Should I fill it all up with topsoil or can I lay other type of soil (please recommend) at the bottom and just do 2” of topsoil once levelled up?